# Is it safe to use the deprecated Android class (Gallery)?

Tags: android, api, gallery, scrollview, deprecated

I realized that `Gallery` class in Android is deprecated, but I can still build my application and it runs correctly.

I don't care much about performance, since it will contain 2-3 pictures at most.

What I'm wondering is, is it safe to use Gallery ?

Will it work in all devices (including API > 16)?

And I hope that Android Dev Team replaces Gallery with another widget, instead of making us write our own galleries using HorizontalScrollView etc.

Comment: you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983571/why-is-the-android-widget-gallery-deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain functionality deprecated by the Android Engineers just to make the developers use a newer implementation of the same. For example the Dialog Fragment requires a lot of coding to do the same task a showDialog() can possibly do. You are completely safe on this one as far as I know. At the same time, there are some other deprecation made due to security issues as well. In the case of Gallery, I understand that there is nothing wrong with using the deprecated class, except that it is deprecated. You are safe.